# WPF Bind DataGridTExtCol with its header cheeckbox

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, checkbox, textbox

In my DataGrid, I have a textcolumn, who has a checkbox in its header.

```
   <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=value1}" >
       <DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                       
            <Grid>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                      <ColumnDefinition/>
                      <ColumnDefinition/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Value1" IsEnabled="{Binding Value1Checked}" />
                <CheckBox Name="chkValue1" Grid.Column="0" Width="16" IsChecked="{Binding Path=Value1Checked, Mode=TwoWay}"  />
           </Grid>
      </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                    
   </DataGridTextColumn>
```

I want to bind the Checkbox value with the Textbox - If the checkbox is selected, then only user can enter value in textbox. 
In my code behind I have :

```
public bool Value1Checked { get; set; }

// In constructor
Value1Checked = false;
```

Now, I believe the app should not allow to enter text in TExtBox of the row as its IsEnabled value has the property Value1Cheched i.e. false. Unless user clicks Value1 checkbox, it shouldn't let the user add it. But the above code has no impact. User is still able to enter value in text block regardless of the value of check box.

Where am I going wrong ??

**ADDITIONAL INFO**
The header contains a Checkbox and text "Value1". And I want to make the user enable/disable to enter value based on the check box clicked on the header.

Any guidelines or help, please.

Thanks

**UPDATED XML CODE**

```
                        <DataGridTemplateColumn>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                                <Grid>
                                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                        <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="TValue1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue1, Path=IsChecked}" />
                                    <CheckBox Name="chkValue1" Grid.Column="0" Width="16" />
                                </Grid>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Value1Checked}" />
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
                         <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue1, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=value1, Mode=TwoWay}" />
                         </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
               </DataGridTemplateColumn>

           </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
```

With this, if I check the checkbox then only I am able to enter values in that col for each row. BUT, by default the value in that col of each row is "FALSE", when I enter text I enter (int) "23" and on focus lost it again shows "FALSE" only. Still what is going wrong ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may be what you want. A checkbox at top that toggles whether all the column's rows can be typed in to. Unfortunately `DatagridTextColumn`'s `IsReadOnly` can't be bound to, so you have to use `DataGridTemplateColumn`, but the end result is the same

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" Text="Value1" IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue1, Path=IsChecked}" />
            <CheckBox Name="chkValue1" Grid.Column="0" Width="16" />
        </Grid>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.Header>
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=myProperty}" />
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <TextBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=chkValue1, Path=IsChecked}" Text="{Binding Path=myProperty, Mode=TwoWay}" />
            </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellEditingTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: when I move the focus from the textbox it throws "Invalid Operation Exception" "Two-way binding required Path or XPath.

Comment: I added "Value1Changed" in SampleData, but then in the rows of that col I am able to enter only bool value & not int. ???? I added the xml code above in "Updated Code"

Comment: @Tvd `Text="{Binding Path=Value1Checked}"` for your `TextBlock` should be `Text="{Binding Path=value1}`

Comment: Oh Jim, Thanks a lot. This finally works. Jim now also help me with row wise. For the same above grid I have a checkbox col on 1st grid, and if that is clicked then only enable user to enter other cols of the row. I need that option also. The solution you had provided isn't working, so. Please help me with that point also.

Comment: @Tvd you should open a new question with your updated solution and ask about your new requirement of row enabling on top of column enabling.

Comment: Jim, have added the Q at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18494066/c-sharp-wpf-datagrid-enable-row-elements-on-selection-of-1st-col-checkbox-of-the

Answer (score 0):

How about binding the `IsReadOnly` property of a `TextBox` to the `Checkbox.IsChecked` property?:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=value1}" >
    <DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                       
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
                <ColumnDefinition/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <TextBox Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked, 
ElementName=chkValue}" />
            <CheckBox Name="chkValue1"  Grid.Column="0" Width="16" IsChecked="{Binding 
RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type DataGridColumn}}, Path=
DataContext.AllItemsAreChecked}" />
        </Grid>
    </DataGridTextColumn.Header>                                    
</DataGridTextColumn>
```

Comment: Oh am Sorry. This changes is affecting the header part and not the actual TextBox in the row of the DataGrid. For that I tried the same thing on "<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Path=value1}" IsReadOnly="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=chkValue1}"  >" but it makes no difference.